# Finding if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n+1/n}{(n+1/n)^n}$ is convergent or divergent .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is this series convergent or divergent ?
 (The sum will be infinite or it will converge to a certain number?)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n+1/n}{(n+1/n)^n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please take a look at the [tour page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider editing your question to comply with the [homework questions guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). In particular, it is good practice to give some context on what course you are taking and show your work in attempting to solve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly ignore the term $\dfrac1n$ at the numerator and

$$\sum\frac{n^n}{(n+\frac1n)^n}=\sum\frac1{(1+\frac1{n^2})^n}$$ diverges as the general term tends to $1$.

Comment: At first, I lost the n^n term at the numerator.

Comment: Shouldn’t we use one of the series tests to answer this question?

Comment: @Negarrezaei: it is enough to note that as $(1+1/n^2)^n=\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n^2)^{n^2}}$, the general term goes to $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust even befor simplifying , the sum of the very first 3 characters of the series would be 2.45. How can the sum of the whole characters of the series from 1 to infinitive would be convergent to 1 ?

Comment: @Negar: I am talking about the general term, not the partial sums. And I said that the sum diverges !!!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I got that thanks.